# php composer not pulling latest version (4.2) of font awesome

Tags: php, composer-php, font-awesome

Hi I'm trying to use one of the new 4.2 icons and noticed that it wasn't showing. I ran composer update and it reported that it had the latest packages. After updating my PHP composer.jason file to forcefully recognise 4.2 it reported the following error.

```
# composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package components/font-awesome could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Is there a reason why I can't use 4.2 since it is listed under what's new section rather than coming soon which it appears to be?

Apart from this little issue I'm finding the icons pretty cool but there is quite a few  symbols missing like:

thumbnail icon
resize icon
rename file icon
move file icon
restore icon
blog icon (not sure)
rotate (quarter circle as it looks like a refresh icon)

4.2 has satisfied 2 that I would have put on the list.

I guess it's down to interpretation/use so can't really mark anyone down for it and I guess the library will grow so 10/10 from me.

Cheers
James

Comment: Don't like using the CDN? http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Anyway, the reason you can't use 4.2.0 from Packagist is because it isn't there ~ https://packagist.org/packages/components/font-awesome

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd pull that in using composer's jason file but it begs the question why isn't the composer repository being kept up-to-date?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 3rd party repository. Take it up with the maintainer

Comment: In regards to the CDN link, you don't use composer for that. Simply put a `<link>` tag in your HTML, ie `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: That's exactly what composer is about. Maintaining version control and package management so doing that would mean the difference from updating in a few seconds to updating in a few days.

Comment: As for the thing about it being off-topic, I believe this is a question I've asked on here so how can it be off topic. Also I did take it up with the maintainer. they asked that I post here before contacting them via email.

Comment: There's nothing anybody here can do to fix the problem therefore, it is off-topic. You could add an issue or pull request on [this repository](https://github.com/components/font-awesome) asking for 4.2 to be incorporated which would make it available to composer but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks Phil - I've just emailed the guy asking when it will be available.

Comment: Which *"guy"*? There are six contributors on that repository.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the sum of the contributors, I was referring to the single guy who said you could try emailing me! http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/community/ And judging by the tone I fear you took my "Thanks Phil" as being derogatory and not the way I intended as a genuine "Thank you".

Comment: I had a feeling you might be talking to the Font Awesome author / contributors. These are not the people you need to talk to. The composer packages on Packagist are not necessarily maintained by the original authors of the tools. The repository backing `components/font-awesome` is maintained by a different group of guys  (Dave isn't one of them) who merge Font Awesome releases into their repo.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Phil for you're help.

After contacting font-awesome I realised that I was pulling in the wrong vendor. I had "components" instead of "fortawesome".

This has now been resolved as 4.2 is available from packagist under the correct vendor name :/

Silly mistake but worth noting.